# Viewpager View getting blank

Tags: android, android-viewpager, sneakers

I am using sneaker for error display message, and I am using Viewpager with views rather then fragment.
Problem is whenever i show a Sneaker for error or something my whole view gets blank.
I tried toast message for the same this problem does not occur when using toast.

Can anyone suggest what may be the problem here.

My Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/leaveFormTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/primaryScreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- Leave Type -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border"
                        android:padding="1dp">

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/leaveTypeSpinner"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/ContentHeaderTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:paddingStart="2dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/leave_type" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">
                    <!-- From Date -->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                            android:padding="3dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/fromDate"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/calender"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                tools:text="12/10/1994" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/ContentHeaderTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                            android:paddingStart="2dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/from_date" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <!-- To Date -->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                            android:padding="3dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/toDate"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/calender"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                tools:text="12/10/1994" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/ContentHeaderTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                            android:paddingStart="2dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/to_date" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
                <!-- Days Applied -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                            android:padding="3dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/daysApplied"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:focusable="false"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                tools:text="2" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/ContentHeaderTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                            android:paddingStart="2dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/no_of_days" />
                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <!--Contact on Leave-->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                            android:padding="3dp">

                            <net.technogen.mocs.view.PrefixEditText
                                android:id="@+id/contactOnLeave"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@color/level_transparent"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:maxLength="12"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:tag="+"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="13sp"
                                tools:text="918655431443" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/ContentHeaderTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                            android:paddingStart="2dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/contact_while_on_leave" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


                <!--Approving Manager-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border"
                        android:padding="3dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/approvingManager"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                            tools:text="PB" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/ContentHeaderTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:paddingStart="2dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/approving_manager" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <!--Reason for Leave-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border"
                        android:padding="3dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/reasonForLeave"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/level_transparent"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:minLines="5"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                            android:textSize="13sp"
                            tools:text="XYZ" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/ContentHeaderTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:paddingStart="2dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/reason_for_leave" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <!--Delegation for Leave-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border"
                        android:padding="3dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/delegationForLeave"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/level_transparent"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:minLines="3"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                            android:textSize="13sp"
                            tools:text="2" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/ContentHeaderTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:paddingStart="2dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/delegation_for_leave" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/submit"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_selector" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/attachmentScreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/attachmentList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <io.github.kobakei.materialfabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
                android:id="@+id/add_voucher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                app:fab_menu="@menu/voucher_menu" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

My sneaker code for error :

```
Sneaker.with(this)
                    .setMessage("No Internet available, Please check your connection")
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_no_signal)
                    .sneak(R.color.colorGray)
```

Comment: As far as I know, ViewPager shouldn't have any childs. Instead, the tab-views should be in a Fragment. Why would you use a ViewPager if you have no tabs? Sorry, might not be a good question, just trying to understand

Comment: I have tabs but we can use view pager by views also rather than fragments

viewPagerAdapter.addView(R.id.primaryScreen, "Details")
viewPagerAdapter.addView(R.id.attachmentScreen, "Attachments")